# VBA Macro: Can't Paste Value

Tags: excel, vba

I have syntax that run smoothly. But, sadly it can't paste value. I've tried :

> .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
>
> .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

This is my syntax...

```
Sub CopasToPenalty()

Dim LRSrc As Long, LRDest As Long, SrcRng As Range
With Sheets("RAW_DATA_PENALTY")
    LRSrc = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set SrcRng = .Range("A2:F" & LRSrc)
End With
With Sheets("PENALTY")
    LRDest = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    SrcRng.Copy .Cells(LRDest + 1, 2) 'NOT YET PASTE VALUE
End With

End Sub
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you just need the values? Try `.Range(.Cells(LRDest+1,2),.Cells(LRDest+1+SrcRng.Rows.Count,2)).Value = SrcRng.Value`?

Comment: @BruceWayne that syntax only paste 1 column.

Comment: Change `Cells(LRDest+1+SrcRng.Rows.Count,2)` to `Cells(LRDest+1+SrcRng.Rows.Count,6)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SrcRng.Copy .Cells(LRDest + 1, 2)` This will not paste just values. It will paste formats and other stuff as well.

Try the below.

**Way One** Using PasteSpecial

```
SrcRng.Copy 
.Cells(LRDest + 1, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

**Way Two** Using Resize

```
Dim destRng As Range
Set destRng = .Cells(LRDest + 1, 2)
destRng.Resize(SrcRng.Rows.Count, SrcRng.Columns.Count).Value = SrcRng.Value
```

Comment: thank you so much. my syntax run smoothly using PasteSpecial. i've tried PasteSpecial but didn't works. it turns out that the syntax has to be put in a new line.

Comment: my wrong syntax: `SrcRng.Copy .Cells(LRDest + 1, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`