# Export Multiple Columns from Excel to single text file using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Excel Description:

```
Columns A B C D E F G H I J K L  M      N      O  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y  Z   AA
Months  J F M A M J J A S O N D  Total  Blank  J1 F1 M1 A1 M1 J1 J1 A1 S1 O1 N1 D1  Total
Data
```

Text File Output

```
Months Data
J 
F
. 
.
D
J1
F1
.
.
D1
```

Comment: Please include the code you are using to solve this in your question if you would like help with it.

Comment: copy values to the new sheet [use way two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58965870/vba-macro-cant-paste-value) and [save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34155718/vba-saving-single-sheet-as-csv-not-whole-workbook) it.